# NVD3 chart in React app draws html that do not ever then disappear from the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, nvd3.js

I implemented an `NVD3` scatter chart in a `React` app and when I am hovering over it the tooltip is shown which sometimes does not go away:

[image]

Basically the cursor was already moved away from the chart, but these two labels just got stuck there and now if I navigate to the other page they stay there:

[image]

The bug is definitely related to the chart being re-drawn sometimes. I suppose that the previously drawn chart is re-drawn by the new one and so loses the handle to the tooltip.

I tried controlling the bug with `shouldComponentUpdate()` function but was just able to reduce the occurrence of the bug, but it is still happening.

Then, I tried to find the html for the drawn tooltips, so that I could write code to just find them and delete from the page, but I was not able to with `Google Chrome` tools. Somehow they are no more in html but are shown on the page...

The tooltip overriding code looks like that:

```
var that = this;
    chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      //var html = "<div>";
      var html = "";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
            if (that.props.type === "main") {
              that.showBarChart(elem.key);
              html = "";
              html += "<p>cluster " + elem.key + "</p>";
   ------>   } else if (that.props.type === "marker") {
              html = "";
              if (elem.type === "main") {
      ------>    html += "<p>cluster " + elem.key + "</p>";
              }
            }
              /*var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";*/
          }
        });
      })
      //html += "</div>";
      return html;
    });
```

I pointed with arrows the code that draws the tooltips. The code above is located within the function `createScatterChart()` which is called from `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` if certain requirements are met (I am trying to minimize the updates since both it leads to less efficient app which redraws my chart many times and to more of the bug in question)

The code for the scatter chart itself is pretty identical to the one that is here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterChart.html

Maybe it is possible to somehow optimize this code, so that the first time the html for the chart is created, and then it is just updated with the data? Is it not already working like that if I call `createScatterChart()`? As I understand it is done by the code `nv.addGraph`, so is there a way to something like `nv.findAndUpdateGraph`?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong is calling all of the code that creates the chart every time any update happens. I fixed it by just updating the data without calling `nv.addGraph()` all the time:

```
  d3.select(node)
    .datum(data_func);
   chart.update()
```

I made `chart` as a global variable, and updated it later on, after it was created with `chart.update()`. The code looks like that:

```
 // If the chart has not yet been created, run `nv.addGraph()` 
 if(d3.select(".nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-scatterChart").empty()) {
     ...
     ...
 } else {
       d3.select(node)
          .datum(data_func);
       chart.update()
 }
```